# Sublime Text regex to re-order Facebook message export

Tags: regex, facebook, sorting, replace, sublimetext

I've exported my Facebook message history and found that messages are displayed as below. Some are in blocks, some blocks are out of order, some are together, all in reverse.

```
John Doe Sunday, 24 August 2014, 01:18
Hello!

Jane Doe Sunday, 24 August 2014, 01:17
Hi!
```

What I'm trying to do is to use a regex, `[a-z]*` and `$1`, etc., to search and replace in Sublime Text to re-layout the data such that the above becomes sortable in Excel (to get everything in correct order) as below (or any date-sortable manner):

```
2014.08.24 01:17    Jane Doe    Hi
2014.08.24 01:18    John Doe    Hello!
```

Is this possible? I've managed to select the name date and time, but cannot get the variable-length messages consistently and nor re-order/move the date/time or message to the example blow. Does this make sense, or am I wasting my time?

Would it be best in a tab/comma separated way, too?

Comment: "all in reverse" as in Name + Date + Message vs Date + Name + Message etc?

Comment: Each 'block' of messages say a few days is in reverse order, and these blocks seem rather randomly ordered, too. I'll edit my op as I can't do lines here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'd be much better off using your favorite language to parse the HTML in `html/messages.htm`. Open the file in Sublime, use a code formatter like [`HTML-CSS-JS Prettify`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/HTML-CSS-JS%20Prettify) (note: requires Node.js) to format it, then look at the structure. Basically, each conversation is in reverse order, oldest first, and within the conversation each message is sorted most recent first (yay consistency!). Here's an example:

```html
<div class="thread">Fred Smith, Joe Blow
    <div class="message">
        <div class="message_header">
            <span class="user">Fred Smith</span>
            <span class="meta">Monday, June 13, 2011 at 3:42pm EDT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Not much Joe. How are you?</p>
    <div class="message">
        <div class="message_header">
            <span class="user">Joe Blow</span>
            <span class="meta">Monday, June 13, 2011 at 11:00am EDT</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p>Hey there Fred, what&#039;s up?</p>
</div>
```

Comment: I'm only looking for one person's messages, and for me they're oddly scattered, like a 2008 block, then some from 2007, then 2011, then back to 2007, then 2006, and some 2014 mixed in. I cannot work out why. I need to read up on parsing html, I've no idea what I'm facing! Thanks for the posts!